# Task to update google firestore database doesnt complete

Tags: c#

When I run code to insert data in a Google Firestore database, the database gets updated, but the application just freezes as if database operation is not completed.

But when I add a 1000ms timeout in wait, then my code works properly.

```
    private  async Task AddData1(string project)
    {
        FirestoreDb db = FirestoreDb.Create(project);
        DocumentReference docRef = db.Collection("employees").Document("100250");
        Dictionary<string, object> user = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            {"Name","nakshatra"},
            {"Age","7"},
            {"Domicile","Himanchal"}
       };
        label1.Text += "Inserting data to firestore database";

      WriteResult x=  await docRef.SetAsync(user);

        Console.WriteLine(" Data added for employee no 100242");
        label1.Text += "Data Inserted successfully";

    }
```

and the function call is

```
AddData1("testproj1-7d81b").Wait(); //app freezes
AddData1("testproj1-7d81b").Wait(1000); // app works fine
```

After running the code, it should insert the data in a Firestore database. Then should print "Data Inserted successfully";

But instead the app freezes.

Answer (score 1):

[Don't block on `async` code using `Wait`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). The proper way to call asynchronous code is with `await`:

```
await AddData1("testproj1-7d81b");
```

And yes, [this will cause `async` to "grow" through your codebase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx). This is perfectly natural and correct.

Comment: Thanks, this solution has worked for me. I have removed wait and used await instead.